# Prove that if $p, q$ are relatively prime, then so are $p^n, q^n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, coprime

Trying to prove that if $p$ e $q$ are relatively prime and integers then $p^n$ and $q^n$ are prime numbers among themselves too, I wrote:

If $p$ e $q$ are prime numbers among themselves $p\neq m.q$  for any $m\in \Bbb{N}$, then $p^n \neq (m.q)^n = m^n . q^n$. As $m\in\Bbb{N}$ is arbitrary and $m^n\in \Bbb{N}$, so $p^n$ and $q^n$ are prime numbers among themselves too.

But then I remembered that a natural number can be power of an irrational number, for example $(\sqrt{2})^2 = 2$. Therefore, how can I prove this statement?

Comment: As you seem to intuit in your last paragraph, it is at issue what *kind* of numbers $p,q$ are assumed to be.  If we assume $p,q$ are integers (or more narrowly, are natural numbers), then you can apply the [Fundamental Thm. of Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic).  Are you asking about ordinary integers or (perhaps) about extending the claim to more general "numbers"?

Comment: I forgot to say that $p$ and $q$ are integer numbers. @hardmath

Comment: I saw this question now but somehow I didn't really get the explanation.@JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: This fundamental question deserves more than a zero. ;o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Euclid's Lemma states that if a prime number divides a product of numbers then it must divide one of the factors of that product. Let's do this exercise by reductio ad absurdum. Suppose there was a prime number $$x\not= 1: x|p^n , x|q^n$$
By Euclid's Lemma:
$$x|p,x|q$$
But this is absurd because $p,q$ are coprimes.

Comment: Nice proof. Maybe we might also be able to prove this, not as easily, with Bezout's Lemma. 
Since $\gcd (q,p) = 1$ , then there exist $qs + pt = 1$, then $(qs + pt)^n = 1^n $, and by the binomial theorem